# Can I iterate over different data- tags in a tag in a particular order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML I have the following code. Depending on what's being shown it can 
have 0,1,2,3,4 or 5 different time points. The first time period of interest is data-t0 
and then next is data-t1 minus data-t0 etc.

```
<table id="dataTable" data-t2="1828" data-t1="1552" data-t0="1163" ></table>
<h1>Grid data</h1>
```

Is there a way that I can add the times to the h1 tag like this if there at least exists a
timing point data-t0?

```
<h1 title="Response time: t1=1163, t2=11, t3=276">Grid data</h1>
```

The problem I have is that I need some way for it to go through and add in the times
for each of the timing points. I can do simple jQuery but I don't know how to make it
iterate over each of the timing points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just want to store your data in a single attribute using a JSON literal:

```
<table id="dataTable" data-t="[1163, 1552, 1828]" ></table>
```

```
var data = $("#dataTable").data('t'); //jQuery does the JSON parsing for us
var diffs = [];

for(var i = 0; i + 1 < data.length; i++) {
    diffs[i] = data[i + 1] - data[i];
}

alert(diffs.join(', '));
```

Comment: This is very interesting. I did not know that I could store data like that and use JSON. Thanks I will try this out now.

Comment: @Angela: There's no reason you can't put a JSON string anywhere that expects a string. What's special is how jQuery automagically parses it.